# UISearchBarDelegate search button don't work swift 3 iOS 10.3

Tags: ios, swift3, uisearchbardelegate

I had been looking for an answer and I hope you can help me. I don't see mistakes in the code but for some reason the UISearchBarDelegate just don't work when I press the "Search" button.

This is my class

```
class BusquedaViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var searchBar: UISearchBar!
var referencias: [Reference]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 20))
    searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    searchBar.delegate = self
    self.parent?.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
    referencias = DataManager.sharedInstance.obtenerReferencias()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.parent?.title = "Busqueda"
}

//MARK: UISearchBar
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    var placa = searchBar.text
    if text.isEmpty {
        return true
    } else {
        let uper = text.uppercased()
        let allowed = "1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ-"
        if !allowed.contains(uper) || (placa?.characters.count)! > 9 {
            return false
        }
        searchBar.text = searchBar.text! + uper
        return false
    }
}

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
    searchBar.text = ""
    searchBar.endEditing(true)
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.endEditing(true)
}

//MARK: UITableView
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return referencias.isEmpty ? 1 : referencias.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    if referencias.isEmpty {
        //cell.textLabel?.text = NSLocalizedString("NO_REFERENCIAS", comment: "")
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = referencias[indexPath.row].model
    }
    return cell
}
}
```

Comment: the other delegates are called or not

Comment: Are you sure you are adding search bar through code not from Storyboard ?

Comment: actually everything works, except for the "searchBarSearchButtonClicked"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess, but the `shouldChangeTextIn range:` method is returning false for the return key (character `\n`), and that could be affecting the other delegate method. Can you try modifying the method to use the below implementation, and see if the `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` method is called?

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, 
               replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: No problem. Feel free to up-vote the answer as well if it helped you.